Trying to make R choose a random variable and read a text depending on the variable
I tried to make R roll a D20 and say a prompted text line with specific random variables between 1 and 20.
d20roll <- sample(1:20,1,replace=FALSE);d20roll
ifelse(d20roll>18 & d20roll<21,'Summon a dragon')
ifelse(d20roll>12 & d20roll<18,'Cast haste on the nearest archer')
ifelse(d20roll<12,'Go directly to jail, do not pass go','reroll')


12 and 18 do not fall into any group. Is it intentional?

ifelse() and & only make sense vor vector arguments. For single values, use if  and &&.

Here is a solution with findInterval.
cut_points <- c(0, 12, 18, 21, Inf)
action <- c(
  'Go directly to jail, do not pass go',
  'Cast haste on the nearest archer',
  'Summon a dragon',
  'reroll'
)

set.seed(2024)
d20roll <- sample(20L, 1L); d20roll
#> [1] 2
i <- findInterval(d20roll, cut_points)
action[i]
#> [1] "Go directly to jail, do not pass go"

Created on 2024-09-08 with reprex v2.1.0

Note that findInterval is vectorized so if you want  to run it R times, just change the call to sample to sampling with replacement.
R <- 100L
d20roll <- sample(20L, R, replace = TRUE)
i <- findInterval(d20roll, cut_points)
action[i] |> table()
#> 
#>    Cast haste on the nearest archer Go directly to jail, do not pass go 
#>                                  35                                  50 
#>                     Summon a dragon 
#>                                  15

Created on 2024-09-08 with reprex v2.1.0
